# database is missing in flutter application

Tags: flutter

i have problem with a flutter application that use SQLite and i have this error telling me that my database is missing

```
    Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device SM J500H...
Restarted application in 3,157ms.
E/SQLiteLog(22873): (1) no such table: employeeTable
E/flutter (22873): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table: employeeTable (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, age, city, department, description, name FROM employeeTable
E/flutter (22873): #################################################################
E/flutter (22873): Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
E/flutter (22873): Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
E/flutter (22873):  (no such table: employeeTable (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, age, city, department, description, name FROM employeeTable)
E/flutter (22873): #################################################################) sql 'SELECT id, age, city, department, description, name FROM employeeTable' args []}
E/flutter (22873): #0      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:12:7)
E/flutter (22873): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22873): #1      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/factory_impl.dart:30:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

it solved by delete the app and reinstall it ...
as i realised that the database versin is the problem...i hope it helps somone